# Integration involving Error function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, error-function

I am interested in the following integral $$\int_0^\infty x^n \,\textbf{Erf}[ax]\,j_m(bx) \,\mathrm{d}x,$$ where **Erf** is the error function $j_n$ is the spherical Bessel function of first kind. Does the analytical solution exist to this integral for $0<n<2$, and $a,b>0$ and $m\geq2$?

Comment: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf
check this table maybe u will find something